# Documentation for Web Service testing with SoapUI

Tags: tools, web-service, soapui

I am new in web service testing with SoapUI. I refer SoapUI own documentation resource for testing. But their is not discussed all features step by step properly. And not also discussed for advanced web service testing.

Please say some good resource  for web service testing with SoapUI not SoapUI pro.

N.T- I will be thankful if anyone post his own web service testing process video tutorial with SoapUI not SoapUi pro.

Comment: I suggest to change this into community wiki.

Comment: @dzieciou I disagree - either it's a good question and people should get credit for their answers, or it's not a good question and it should be closed. I would vote to close, but i'm not 10000% certain and obviously my vote is binding, which is why I'm letting the community decide.

Comment: @corsiKa: We had multiple questions where there was no single answer, e.g., books recommendations or resources to learn: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing, and they were community wikis. Given that why this one cannot be treated like that?

Comment: That implies that 1) that's a good question and 2) that this question and that question are in the same category. I'm not sure about either of those implications being true.

Comment: Also, I think the guidance on use of community wiki has changed over time. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/ has a good overview.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this great blog: http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/web-services-api-testing-tool-soapui-tutorial-1/

Second you can check the free courses here: http://soapui-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 0):

I too, have not found any good SoapUI tutorials.

Here is a video of data-driven testing reading from Excel, using a public webservice with the free version (open source) of SoapUI 5.4.0.

The code and instructions are provided in the Comments so you can play with this framework.

URL = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2aNSUZtFRY&t=1s