# Online application with a bug to learn troubleshooting of HTTP traffic

Tags: interview

Is there any online Web application with known bugs that I could use to verify candidate's skills in troubleshooting?

In particular I am looking for something that will allow a candidate to demonstrate understanding of HTTP traffic with Developer Tools/Network, Firebug or similar tools in a Web browser.

Comment: Well, there are broad questions like this http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing here (recommended books) and you're voting for this to be closed as too broad? Where's the difference?

Comment: Closing mafia strikes again? I think I know who the closers are.

Comment: @PeterMasiar This makes me stop from contributing to this community. I have nothing against closing my questions, but I would like to get feedback. Giving feedback is not obligatory when downvoting or closing, but neither my contribution here are.

Comment: I exactly know how you feel. I already dialed down my contributions here and abandoned few communities (not this one). Few newish members, who gained most of experience points by making trivial edits, and not by valuable answers, are running the show now. It's a shame. But this is pattern everywhere (the tragedy of commons), and they are allowed to game the rules - they are not breaking them, just gaming them. If they succeed in closing this one, msg me, I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @TESTasy, there are broad questions like this http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing here (recommended books) and you voted for this to be closed as too broad? Where's the difference?

Comment: @NarendraC, there are broad questions like this http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing here (recommended books) and you voted for this to be closed as too broad? Where's the difference?

Comment: @BharatMane, there are broad questions like this  http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing here (recommended books) and you voted for this to be closed as too broad? Where's the difference?

Comment: Exactly the closing mafia I suspected, running amok. Voted to reopen

Answer (score 1):

[ToDoInterviewTest](https://github.com/TheJambo/ToDoInterviewTest) is available at GitHub and among other bugs, it has:

- Inappropriate comment in source code.
- Two 404 errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

[The internet](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/) has a bunch of common html elements any test automation engineer will encounter, like frames, images, tables, complex locators, download links and so on...